# How can you easily measure your visual range?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, vision

There are numerous ways of estimating your hearing range by generating sine waves at a certain amplitude and trying to tell when you are no able to hear a difference between on and off anymore. An example of such a generator would be [this hearing range test.](http://onlinetonegenerator.com/hearingtest.html)

Is there a simple way to test the same for the visual range? "Simple" in the sense that it requires few, cheap or already commonly available materials or technologies such as computer screens, sheets of colored foil etc. The goal is to be able to pinpoint the personal visual range with fairly good accuracy of roughly $\pm 10$ nm, for example $[380 - 770]$nm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie it is a question about methodology in experimental physics in my opinion

Comment: it is better for cognitive science, lots of psychophysicists there

Comment: Unlike your hearing, which depends on the functioning of millions of cells in your ears, your vision is given by three chemicals in your eyes, so unless you have a genetic change in the genes that are responsible for the synthesis of these molecules, your vision is the same as that of everybody else. In most cases this means that you are color blind, in rare cases you may have a fourth molecule that lets you see one more color band than most people.

Comment: So, then what is a more exact visual range compared to the range that is commonly cited (see above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to mind is separating white light (e.g. from the sun) through a prism, and using the colors in the spectrum with corresponding wavelength to determine what range you can see.

Comment: How can you easily tell the wavelength from this part of the spectrum you split off?

Comment: Perhaps find the refraction index for each wavelength with a given material used for prism, then check the angle of deviation.. There should be formulas for these, but I'm not very good at it. I'm also not very sure if it would have acceptable accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

There are devices called Monochromators, which can produce narrow band illumination with pretty good accuracy, so if implemented correctly, one may measure the visual range of a person, I would believe.